# Android collision detection implementation

Tags: java, android, opengl-es-1.1

I am making a space shooting game for Android and I am experiencing some problems with the collision detection between enemy and player ship(// Detect enemy collision with player). I 'ld appreciate if anyone can help me with the best way to approach this. check out my detectCollisions()  below:

**private void detectCollisions(){

```
    // Detect enemy collision with player; to be revised
    for (int z = 0; z < SSEngine.TOTAL_INTERCEPTORS + SSEngine.TOTAL_SCOUTS + SSEngine.TOTAL_WARSHIPS - 1; z++ ){
    if(enemies[z].posX <= SSEngine.playerBankPosX 
            && enemies[z].posY <= SSEngine.playerBankPosX )
    {
        player1.applyDamage(); 
    }
    }

    //Detect Player's fire 
    for (int y = 0; y < 3; y ++)

        if (playerFire[y].shotFired){
            for (int x = 0; x < SSEngine.TOTAL_INTERCEPTORS + SSEngine.TOTAL_SCOUTS + SSEngine.TOTAL_WARSHIPS - 1; x++ ){


                if(!enemies[x].isDestroyed && enemies[x].posY < 4.25 ){



                    if ((playerFire[y].posY >= enemies[x].posY - 1 
                            && playerFire[y].posY <= enemies[x].posY ) 
                            && (playerFire[y].posX <= enemies[x].posX + 1 
                            && playerFire[y].posX >= enemies[x].posX - 1)){
                        int nextShot = 0;
                        enemies[x].applyDamage();
                        playerFire[y].shotFired = false;
                        if (y == 3){
                            nextShot = 0;
                        }else{
                            nextShot = y + 1;
                        }
                        if (playerFire[nextShot].shotFired == false){
                            playerFire[nextShot].shotFired = true;
                            playerFire[nextShot].posX = SSEngine.playerBankPosX;
                            playerFire[nextShot].posY = 1.25f;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }**
```

Answer (score 0):

Your check in `if` is wrong-

if,

`playerFire[y].posY >= enemies[x].posY - 1` is true
how come

`playerFire[y].posY <= enemies[x].posY`will hold true?

And you are ANDING true && false, so it will always be false.

Comment: The condition will be true only iff playerFire[y].posY is exactly equal to enemies[x].posY

Comment: The condition will be true if difference between positions less or equals 1.

Comment: Thanks Rajkiran and Sergey, can you please show me what the codes should look like because I'm completely lost.